# How to use keras with scikit-learn when you have multidimensional input and multiple outputs with a CAPTCHA dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, conv-neural-network, grid-search

I want to predict text-based CAPTCHA with a convolutional neural network. I am trying to use scikit-learn GridSearchCV in Keras to fine tune the model with [Scikeras](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/) library. My model has five outputs to predict each character of CAPTCHA and a multi-dimensional input: the image. The used dataset is [CAPTCHA Images](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/fournierp/captcha-version-2-images).

I tried to use [SciKeras Data Transformers](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/notebooks/DataTransformers.html) to solve this problem with this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/scikeras-tutorial-a-multi-input-multi-output-wrapper-for-capsnet-hyperparameter-tuning-with-keras-3127690f7f28) but I stuck with it. This is the error message, which I got:

```
ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of multilabel-indicator and multiclass-multioutput targets
```

In the beginning, the shape of the trainable x and y are the followings:

```
train_X shape: (856, 50, 200, 1)
train_y shape: (5, 856, 36)
```

Here is my MO.py file with the MultiOutputTransformer and MultiOutputClassifier classes.

```py
from typing import List
import numpy as np
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer


class MultiOutputTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, y):
        y_0 = y[:, :36]
        y_1 = y[:, 36:72]
        y_2 = y[:, 72:108]
        y_3 = y[:, 108:144]
        y_4 = y[:, 144:180]

        self.n_classes_ = [y_0.shape[1],
                           y_1.shape[1],
                           y_2.shape[1],
                           y_3.shape[1],
                           y_4.shape[1]]

        self.n_outputs_expected_ = 5
        return self

    def transform(self, y: np.ndarray) -> List[np.ndarray]:
        y_0 = y[:, :36]
        y_1 = y[:, 36:72]
        y_2 = y[:, 72:108]
        y_3 = y[:, 108:144]
        y_4 = y[:, 144:180]

        return [y_0, y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4]

    def inverse_transform(self, y: List[np.ndarray], return_proba: bool = False) -> np.ndarray:
        y_pred_proba = y  # rename for clarity, what Keras gives us are probs
        if return_proba:
            return np.column_stack(y_pred_proba, axis=1)

        y_pred_0 = np.argmax(y_pred_proba[0], axis=1)
        y_pred_1 = np.argmax(y_pred_proba[1], axis=1)
        y_pred_2 = np.argmax(y_pred_proba[2], axis=1)
        y_pred_3 = np.argmax(y_pred_proba[3], axis=1)
        y_pred_4 = np.argmax(y_pred_proba[4], axis=1)

        return np.column_stack([y_pred_0, y_pred_1, y_pred_2, y_pred_3, y_pred_4])

    def get_metadata(self):
        return {
            "n_classes_": self.n_classes_,
            "n_outputs_expected_": self.n_outputs_expected_
        }


input_shape = (50, 200, 1)


class MultiOutputClassifier(KerasClassifier):

    @property
    def target_encoder(self):
        return MultiOutputTransformer()

    @property
    def feature_encoder(self):
        return FunctionTransformer(
            func=lambda X: X.reshape(X.shape[0], *input_shape),
        )

    @staticmethod
    def scorer(y_true, y_pred, **kwargs):
        y_0 = y_true[:, :36]
        y_1 = y_true[:, 36:72]
        y_2 = y_true[:, 72:108]
        y_3 = y_true[:, 108:144]
        y_4 = y_true[:, 144:180]

        y_pred_0 = y_pred[:, :36]
        y_pred_1 = y_pred[:, 36:72]
        y_pred_2 = y_pred[:, 72:108]
        y_pred_3 = y_pred[:, 108:144]
        y_pred_4 = y_pred[:, 144:180]

        return np.mean([accuracy_score(y_0, y_pred_0),
                        accuracy_score(y_1, y_pred_1),
                        accuracy_score(y_2, y_pred_2),
                        accuracy_score(y_3, y_pred_3),
                        accuracy_score(y_4, y_pred_4)])
```

Here is my main.py file:

```py
import string
import zipfile
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import random
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from grid_search_cv_keras import MO
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.utils.multiclass import type_of_target

images_names = []
labels = []
X_list = []
filename = "captcha-version-2-images.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as zipper:
    for p in zipper.namelist():
        if ".png" in p or ".jpg" in p:
            with zipper.open(p) as f:
                image_name = p.split("/")[-1]
                images_names.append(image_name)

                label = image_name.split(".")[0]
                labels.append(label)

                img = mpimg.imread(f)
                img = img[:, :, 0]
                img = np.reshape(img, (50, 200, 1))
                X_list.append(img)
index = list(range(len(X_list)))
random.shuffle(index)
X = np.asarray(X_list)
X = X[index]
labels = np.array(labels)[index]
characters = "0123456789" + string.ascii_lowercase
y = np.zeros(shape=(5, len(labels), len(characters)))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(len(labels)):
        y[i][j][characters.index(labels[j][i])] = 1

train_X = X[:int(0.8 * len(X))]
train_y = y[:, :int(0.8 * len(X)), :]
validation_X = X[int(0.8 * len(X)):int(0.9 * len(X))]
validation_y = y[:, int(0.8 * len(X)):int(0.9 * len(X)), :]
test_X = X[int(0.9 * len(X)):]
test_y = y[:, int(0.9 * len(X)):, :]

def create_model(dropout_rate=0.2):
    image = keras.layers.Input((50, 200, 1))
    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(image)
    mp1 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp1)
    mp2 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(conv2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(mp2)
    bn = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    flat = keras.layers.Flatten()(bn)
    out = []
    for _ in range(5):
        den1 = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu")(flat)
        drop1 = keras.layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(den1)
        den2 = keras.layers.Dense(len(characters), activation="softmax")(drop1)
        out.append(den2)

    model = keras.Model(image, out)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

n_samples_train = train_X.shape[0]
x_train = train_X.reshape((n_samples_train, -1))

tf = MO.MultiOutputTransformer()
y = [train_y[0], train_y[1], train_y[2], train_y[3], train_y[4]]
y_sklearn = np.column_stack(y)

param_grid = {
    'batch_size': [16],
    'epochs': [5],
    'dropout_rate': [0.1],
}

clf = MO.MultiOutputClassifier(model=create_model, random_state=0, dropout_rate=0.1)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=clf, verbose=3, param_grid=param_grid, scoring='accuracy')
gs_res = grid_search.fit(x_train, y_sklearn)
```

This is how my x_train and y_train look like after I transform and reshape them:

```py
x_train shape = (856, 10000)
[[0.7529412 0.7529412  0.7529412 ... 0.99607843 0.99607843 0.99607843]
 [0.7529412 0.7529412  0.7529412 ... 0.99607843 0.99607843 0.99607843]
 [0.7529412 0.7529412  0.7529412 ... 0.99607843 0.99607843 0.99607843]
 ...
 [0.7529412 0.7529412  0.7529412 ... 0.99607843 0.99607843 0.99607843]
 [0.7529412 0.7529412  0.7529412 ... 0.99607843 0.99607843 0.99607843]
 [0.7529412 0.7529412  0.7529412 ... 0.99607843 0.99607843 0.99607843]]

y_sklearn shape = (856, 180)
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

print(type_of_target(y_sklearn)) # result: multilabel-indicator
```

Comment: There might be some clues for you [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11656)